# ASP.Net MVC App Stored XSS vulnerability reported by Checkmarx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, xss, checkmarx

Code has been analyzed by Checkmarx and reported the following issue:

> Method `Load_Bank` at line ** gets data from the database, for the `Where` element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly filtered or encoded and is eventually displayed to the user in method `Bank_Read` at line * of `SomeController.cs`. This may enable a **Stored Cross-SiteScripting** attack.

```
internal IEnumerable<BankDTO> Load_Bank()
{
    using (var Container = new EBookletEntities())
    {
        var query = from r in Container.Gen_Bank.AsNoTracking()
                    where r.IsDeleted != true
                    select new Gen_BankDTO
                    {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Name = r.Name
                    };
        return query.ToList<BankDTO>();
    }
}
```

Below is the controller code

```
using (var bll = new BankBLL())
{
    var item = bll.Load_Bank();
    var model = item.Select(r => new BVM()
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            Name = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(r.Name)
        }).ToList();

    return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Checkmarx source:

```
where r.IsDeleted != true
```

Destination:

```
return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I wonder if there is really a Stored XSS issue or Checkmarx reported it false?

How to resolve the Checkmarx issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exploitable, because the response type is `application/json`. Even if there was a valid xss attack with a script tag, no modern browser will execute that in a response with an `application/json` content type.

Also `Id` I guess is a number or uuid and `Name` is html encoded, which you could argue is for defense in depth, but it only actually needs to be encoded for json, which it is inherently.

You can mark this as not exploitable in Checkmarx.

Also note that returning a json array in a GET request is still not considered good practice because of an old attack called [json hijacking](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/). However, this is not exploitable anymore in modern browsers, so I would not say it's vulnerable anymore, *except* in IE9, which might still be in use unfortunately.